# Error MSB8020, changed build tools, still not working

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, ogre

I'm trying to install the ogre sdk for Visual Studio 2012 express as per [these](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Installing+the+Ogre+SDK) instructions, but when I try to build the ALL_BUILD project, I get this error:

Error   1   error MSB8020: The builds tools for v140 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v140 to build using the v140 build tools.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets   44  5   Sample_VolumeTex

I looked into project properties and indeed the platform tool set was set to v140, and so I changed it to v110 but I'm still getting the same MSB8020 error. I also tried right clicking the solution, but there's no option to update vc++ projects. Can someone please help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: You should download the SDK matching your building toolset! For `vc11` use the one labeled "OGRE 1.9 SDK for Visual C++ 2012 (32-bit)" [on the download site](http://www.ogre3d.org/download/sdk) (for `1.9`)

Comment: That's the version I have! That's presumably why it threw the MSB8020 error when the platform toolset was set to v140. So I switched the platform toolset to v110, but I still get the same error.

Comment: well, I've downloaded, unzipped and see `v110` for toolset of `ALL_BUILD` project (ofc i canceled one-way upgrade, since I opened it with newer studio)